# How can I make a collection in Laravel, where same keys will combine?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Using Laravel 8, I want to count travelers who visit my tourist information center. Traveler comes to our info center, asks anything, our employee gives necessary information and then we ask for travelers nationality to count for the statistic reasons.

For example, if the traveler is from Germany, an employee adds him into our stats table submitting a form. If any country repeats, I want to combine them with their counts.

For all of this, I have `countries` table and `counts` table. `countries` table has only string `name`, `counts` table has integer `country_id` and integer `count`.

This is `StatController` where I want to return stats:

```php
return view('stats.counter', [
    'stats' => Stat::groupBy('country_id', 'count')
        ->selectRaw('group_concat(country_id) as country, group_concat(count) as visitor')
        ->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())
        ->get()
]);
```

This is how I get the stats:

```json
[
    {
        "country": "1,1",
        "visitor": "1,1"
    },
    {
        "country": "1",
        "visitor": "2"
    },
    {
        "country": "1",
        "visitor": "4"
    },
    {
        "country": "1",
        "visitor": "6"
    },
    {
        "country": "2",
        "visitor": "5"
    },
    {
        "country": "2",
        "visitor": "8"
    },
    {
        "country": "3",
        "visitor": "1"
    },
    {
        "country": "5",
        "visitor": "4"
    },
    {
        "country": "8",
        "visitor": "4"
    },
    {
        "country": "9",
        "visitor": "5"
    },
    {
        "country": "11",
        "visitor": "3"
    }
]
```

I am doing something wrong, but don't know what, can you help me?

Comment: Without knowing what's in the database, nobody will be able to help. Why use `GROUP_CONCAT` if you have a "counts" table; why not just get counts from there?

Comment: @miken32 what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a solution for me:

```
return view('stats.counter', [
    'stats' => Stat::select([
           'country_id',
           'count' => DB::raw('SUM(count) as count')
        ])
        ->groupBy('country_id')
        ->orderBy('count', 'DESC')
        ->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())
        ->get()
]);
```